# How can I use multiple gcm_sender_id for web push notification with firebase in a single project

Tags: firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, manifest, web-push

Trying to create web push notification with firebase and need to add two gcm_sender_id in manifest.json(same file) but it accepts only one id and in string only. 
Need to add these two gcm_sender_id. So that I can migrate all my subscribers from another platform to FCM.

```
{
     "gcm_sender_id": "9***********",
     "gcm_sender_id": "103953800507"
}
```

If I use gcm_sender_id of FCM then I am unable to send web push notification from the old platform. On the other hand If I use the sender ID of old platform instead of FCM then my Token is not getting generated. Else everything is working fine.
Unable to find anything. Is there any solution?